# Error from rollingmedian using columns

Tags: r, median

I have a dataframe for which I try to add additional column calculating the median of the current and the previous 2 values.

```
Date         Value
21/07/2016  14.8
22/07/2016  14.9
23/07/2016  15.8
24/07/2016  15.0
25/07/2016  15.7
26/07/2016  15.6
27/07/2016  16.1
28/07/2016  16.1
```

I used the following code:

```
library(zoo)
dataframe$medianval <-rollmedian(dataframe$Value,k=3)
```

I get the following error

```
> Error: k <= n is not TRUE
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Think about what R is trying to do here.  The data frame has `8` rows, but the vector you want to append has only `6` elements.  To which rows should those elements align?  What should R put in the other two spots?

```
library(zoo)
dataframe <- read.table(text="Date         Value
21/07/2016  14.8
22/07/2016  14.9
23/07/2016  15.8
24/07/2016  15.0
25/07/2016  15.7
26/07/2016  15.6
27/07/2016  16.1
28/07/2016  16.1", header=TRUE)
rollmedian(dataframe$Value,k=3)
# [1] 14.9 15.0 15.7 15.6 15.7 16.1
nrow(dataframe)                          # [1] 8
length(rollmedian(dataframe$Value,k=3))  # [1] 6
```

Because I can guess what you meant (correct me if I'm wrong), I would try:

```
dataframe$medianval <- c(NA, NA, rollmedian(dataframe$Value,k=3))
dataframe
#         Date Value medianval
# 1 21/07/2016  14.8        NA
# 2 22/07/2016  14.9        NA
# 3 23/07/2016  15.8      14.9
# 4 24/07/2016  15.0      15.0
# 5 25/07/2016  15.7      15.7
# 6 26/07/2016  15.6      15.6
# 7 27/07/2016  16.1      15.7
# 8 28/07/2016  16.1      16.1
```

If you want to be able to adapt this conveniently, you should write a simple function:

```
med.fun <- function(var, data, k){
  # Note: variable name must be in quotes
  return(c(rep(NA, k-1), with(data, rollmedian(get(var), k=k))))
}
med.fun("Value", dataframe, 5)
# [1]   NA   NA   NA   NA 15.0 15.6 15.7 15.7
```

Comment: Many thanks gung for your help and clarification. Would there be in a different way than c(NA, NA,... for example in case I want to run a loop testing different median lengths?